# Volvo s60 2011 D3, infotainment system partly working. AC works, no radio/my car settings etc

Tags: electrical, car, volvo, s60

Volvo s60 2011 D3, infotainment system partly working. AC works, no radio/my car settings etc... Also replaced all fuses for infotainment. Would anyone have any ideas as to why the radio and car settings is not working ... only the AC?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering why radio/my car settings is not working, only AC?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are any of the functions that usually come on with the first position of the ignition switch working?

Comment: @Community I would like to use/see again radio/car settings etc... I currently only have AC line displayed. I can use AC, but nothing else in the control panel like sound/volume/media. I posted img where the red square shows what is not working at all.

Comment: @HandyHowie I have button to turn car on. But I have tried many things with this button, but nothing helps.

Comment: I actually found out that amplifier wire is cut probably because of the sliding seat. I have attached img where is visible which wire is cut! Any ideas how I can replace it or what exactly I need to replace?